# How to show/hide a p:button based on a checkbox selection inside a p:datatable?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a simple button,

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <p:commandButton rendered="#{myBean.checkboxSelected}" value="Action" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

which is set to false and  has getters and setters in the bean, that I want to toggle its rendered attribute (or hide/show it) based on whether ANY checkbox inside my p:dataTable is selected. Conversely, if I check one box and uncheck it, I want to be able to hide button as no checkboxes are selected.

My p:dataTable is set up like this.

```
<p:dataTable id="someID"
    selection="#{myBean.mySelectList}"
    rowKey="#{myBean.id}">
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="text-align:center"/>
....
</p:dataTable>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: update it when there is more than one item selected.

Longer answer: On each selection, update the number of items server side (or just count the list) and use that value in a 'rendered' attribute of the button (check if > 0, or do that server side and use a boolean) and update the panelgroup on each ajax call or do that from the server as well.

All plain 'logic' when using JSF, nothing special, nothing fancy

Comment: How am I tracking each selection? I saw that there is a <p:ajax event="rowSelect" is this is how you're saying it I should update the number of items? How do I handle when the 'select all' button is pressed/unpressed?

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the answer

Comment: I'll add something to the answer